# Python executing definition when not instructed

Tags: python, oop

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import random

from random import shuffle
from random import randint

class ship:
    def __init__(self):
        self.database_scientific = 100
        self.database_cultural = 100

def move_on(self):


    def _do_damage(self):
        self = self - randint(5,30)

        print(module)

    system_list = [
        'scientific database', 
        'cultural database'
    ]

    system_list_damaged = {
        'scientific database': _do_damage(self.database_scientific),
        'cultural database': _do_damage(self.database_cultural)
    }

    if randint(0,10) >= 1:
        encounter_type = randint(1,4)
        vulnerable_system = system_list[0]
        vulnerable_system_number_two = system_list[1]
        if encounter_type == 1:
            print("\n[1] Allow it to hit %s. \n[2] Rotate so it hits another part of the ship." % vulnerable_system)

            choice = raw_input("\n> ")

            if choice == 1 and vulnerable_system == "surface probes":
                print("\nThe asteroid crashes into the ship and knocks one of the surface probes loose.")
                self.surface_probes = self.surface_probes - 1
            elif choice == 1:
                print("\nThe asteroid crashes into the %s causing irreparable damage." % vulnerable_system)
                for vulnerable_system in system_list_damaged.keys():
                    system_list_damaged[vulnerable_system](self)
                    break
s = ship()
s.move_on()
```

It is executing the _do_damage() when not explicitly told to when I initialize the move_on() definition. Can anybody explain why this is occurring? I could not find a good answer or solution. I originally had the _do_damage() outside of the move_on(), but that would not allow me to call the _do_damage() definition...

Comment: there are 2 `_do_damage` calls here. look at `system_list_damaged`.

Comment: wait. actually I can't tell. fix your indentation.

Comment: But those should not be executed. That is just a dictionary that allows me to match the system_list with the module to be damaged.

Comment: a function is executed when you call it. you call a function with `()`, and you clearly did that.

Comment: But that dictionary does not call the function... It simply correlates it with human-readable text.

Comment: @JohnGordon: It would, but the dict values aren't functions, so that loop is going to throw a TypeError. The function calls happen back when the dict is created.

Comment: `'scientific database': _do_damage(self.database_scientific)` absolutely _does_ call the function.  It's got parentheses and everything.

Comment: look, you have `_do_damage(self.database_scientific)`. dictionary or not, **this is a function call.** If you want to store the function as a value in a dictionary, just do `d = {'scientific database':_do_damage}` and then to call it, `d['scientific database'](self.database_scientific)`

Comment: @user2357112 yeah, I realized my mistake and deleted that comment.

Comment: Yes. When the user instructs the program to execute that for loop, that is when I want the function called. However, upon `s.move_on()`, the `_do_damage()` is called.

Comment: It looks like you want the dictionary to store a _reference_ to the function, which can later be used to actually _call_ it.  But that's not what you're doing.  You're calling the function and storing the _result_ in the dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function call stored as a value in a dictionary. *This stores the return value of the function call, **not the function itself**.* To call a function stored in a dictionary,

```
system_list_damaged = {
    'scientific database': _do_damage,
}

# call: 
system_list_damaged['scientific database'](self.database_scientific)
```

to pick a random list element from `system_list` (as per your comment),

```
from random import choice
element = choice(system_list)
```

now, to simplify it all, you can do:

```
from random import choice

system_list_damaged = {
    'scientific database': [_do_damage, self.database_scientific]
    'cultural database': [_do_damage, self.database_cultural]
}
# and to call a random one,
function_to_call = choice(system_list_damaged.keys())
system_list_damaged[function_to_call][0](function_to_call[1])
```

Comment: Okay, so how would I do it so it can randomly select an item from the `system_list`, then correlate that to `system_list_damaged`?

Comment: I ran that code, and it seems to have no effect. Is there something wrong with my `_do_damage()` function?

Comment: I don't know because I don't know where the variable `module` comes from.

Comment: Sorry, that was for my own reference. I know it is frowned upon. It is supposed to be `self`.

Comment: well then yes there is a problem with `_do_damage`. A `ship` object is not a subclass of `int`, and it has no `__sub__` method, so you cannot subtract an `int` instance from it.

Comment: So, how would I subtract an `int` from it?

Comment: that is a loaded question right there. see [here](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/)

Comment: I still do not quite understand, but I am sure I can figure it out.